# GO-AWS-SDK to access instance information on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sdk-go

I am referring to the following function in the aws-go SDK : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/aws/client/#New

I am new to aws / go SDK for aws ( more like a weekend project )

I want to create a client on my localhost machine such that it can login on my AWS account and give me a list of all instances running on the aws account.

Right now , i am just trying to log in to the account

source code :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/client"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/client/metadata"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/request"
)


func main() {

    param1:=aws.Config{Region: aws.String("us-east-1") }
    param2:=metadata.ClientInfo{}
    param3:=request.Handlers{}
    awsClient :=client.New(param1,param2,param3)
    fmt.Print(awsClient)
    fmt.Println(awsClient.ClientInfo)

}
```

output:

```
&{{3 0s 0s 0s 0s} {        } {<nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> 0xc0000133a0 <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil>  } {{[] <nil>} {[] <nil>} {[] <nil>} {[] <nil>} {[] <nil>} {[] <nil>} {[] <nil>} {[] <nil>} {[] <nil>} {[] <nil>} {[] <nil>} {[] <nil>} {[] <nil>} {[] <nil>}}}{        }
```

i have my `.aws/credentials` file correctly set up
I can also login via cli and view all my sub accounts.

Again, i am just trying to login to my account on aws.

Please help me in following: 
1) Am i using the correct API / documentation ?

2) What i understand from this output is that , the client can not communicate with aws. Am i correct ?

3) please help me resolve this issue

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check if the IAM user setup in your credential file have access to list EC2 information.
2. Test out this code which simply check for success or fail

```
package main

import (
   "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
   "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/ec2"

   "fmt"
)

func main() {
   // Load session from shared config
   sess := session.Must(session.NewSessionWithOptions(session.Options{
       SharedConfigState: session.SharedConfigEnable,
   }))

   // Create new EC2 client
   ec2Svc := ec2.New(sess)

   // Call to get detailed information on each instance
   result, err := ec2Svc.DescribeInstances(nil)
   if err != nil {
       fmt.Println("Error", err)
   } else {
       fmt.Println("Success", result)
   }
}
```

The [developer guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/welcome.html) is a good place to start as well if you are new to AWS/Go.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have the root level credentials. I have to access all the sub-level IAM accounts and then assume roles. after that i can list all the resources that each individual account has. it is lot more complicated than i thought. Thanks for the answer.